# Override the model error message

Tags: cakephp

On CakePHP 2.2.1, **I'd like to override the model error message from the view**. I have use this code, like the doc said

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('Company.name', 
    array('error' => array('notEmpty' => __('My custom message')))
); ?>
```

but somehow it is not working.

My validation in the model is like this

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => 'notEmpty',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example.... You can write your custom message like this in model...

```
'title' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi Vins, cmiiw, but your code example is to be put in the model. I need to change the default error message from the view.

Comment: Seems to me like you are doing the right thing. If you want to be able to use the translation function in the model, you can override the constructor and set the validation criteria there.

Comment: Hi @muxcmux. Yeah, it seems that translation is the only way to go. It 's a bit too much for me since my app will only use single language.